# How can I convert hex string(or binary number) to signed short? (PHP)

Tags: php, binary, hex, unpack

I'm trying to convert hex string that is `16bit`(=signed short) to signed decimal number in PHP.

(like: 0xFEF5 -> -267)(if convert binary needed, 0xFEF5 -> 1111 1110 1111 0101 -> -267)

I founded `pack` and `unpack` function. then, I wrote some code, but it is parted works.

```
$bin = hex2bin('0020'); //0020 -> 32(dec) 0000 0000 0010 0000(bin)
$res = unpack("c2char", $bin);
//-> $res = ['char1':0,'char2':32] it works!

$bin = hex2bin('FFE3'); //FFE3 -> -29(dec) 1111 1111 1110 0011(bin)
$res = unpack("c2char", $bin);
//-> $res = ['char1':-1, 'char2':-29] it works!
```

but when set `s` parameter on `unpack` because 16bit data, it doesn't work.

```
$bin = hex2bin('0020');
$res = unpack("s*short", $bin);
//-> $res = ['short1': 8192] //not works

$bin = hex2bin('FFE3');
$res = unpack('s*short", $bin);
//-> $res = ['short1': -7169] //not works...
```

if there is other method to hex to decimal with sign without using `unpack`, it is ok. I don't have obsession to use `unpack`.
Or, if there is other method to binary to decimal with sign, it is ok too.

I took a while at google, but I couldn't find out effective method to resolve.

Can anyone help me? 
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried the hexdec function as in the php manual?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php

Comment: `hexdec()` will do the trick, here, but just so that you understand: the `s` format of the `pack()` function is in machine byte order, which in your case is little-endian, when you would have preferred big-endian. Sadly, there is no format for a 16-bit, big-endian, signed integer.

Comment: `$bin = hex2bin('E3FF'); $res = unpack('s*short", $bin); //$res->-29 it works!` thank you Blackhole! I couldn't figure out that trick. Thank you for your help!